# why am I consistently getting malloc errors when I try to delete my 2D array made using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to delete my 2D array, but I consistently get errors when I try to delete it, we have to work backwards so I delete the elements first, then the column array, then the row array. here is my code for the constructor in my class, MyMatrix:

```
    private:
    int m; //rows
    int **ptr; //ptr to first dimension
    int n; // columns

    public:

    MyMatrix() //constructor
    {
        m = 0;
        n = 0;
        ptr = new int*[m];
        int *length_arr = new int[m]; 
        for (int i = 0; i <= m-1; i++)
        {
            *(ptr+i) = new int[n];
            *(length_arr+i) = n;
        }
    }
```

and my destructor looks like this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= m-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
            {
                delete ((*(ptr+i))+j);
            }
            delete[] *(ptr+i);
        }
        delete[] ptr;
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
assg7(2677,0x100de3d40) malloc: *** error for object 0x12d606804: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

I've wracked my brain for where I can fix this, for context, I'm doing an assignment with operator overloading. I specifically need a delete function to work properly for my = assignment overloading since I want to delete and again reallocate memory to equate two matrices, but the terminal is showing malloc errors and is thus not equating the matrices.
for additional info here is my = overloading code:

```
void operator = (const MyMatrix &obj)
    {
        if(n == obj.n && m == obj.m)
        {
         //for loop to equate elements in this-> to the elements of the passed object   
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <= m-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
                {
                    delete ((*(ptr+i))+j);
                }
                delete[] *(ptr+i);
            }
            delete[] ptr;

            // the code for assigning new memory according to the passed objects rows and colums goes here
            //then for loop to equate elements in this-> to the elements of the passed object   
        
        }
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: You only need to `delete` what you did `new`. This doesn't seem to be such a case: `delete ((*(ptr+i))+j);`. (Moreover, a much better approach would be to avoid `new`. Use `std::vector`, namely a vector of vectors, if you are allowed to.)

Comment: *we have to work backwards so I delete the elements first, then the column array* - but you did not allocate elements yourself. You allocated array, and in that array some number of arrays. If you wanted to allocate elements in the array, you would need to ascend to [three-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) level.

Comment: anyway, a code written like this is a real pain to look at, I really struggle at the end of the day to know what ptr is. Thank god `std::vector` exist.

Comment: As an approximation, `new` should not appear in application code.

Comment: Possibly OT: We usually use C++ because we want efficiency and performance. Representing a 2D dense matrix as a dynamic array of arrays would be insane in this perspective. Instead, represent it as a 1D array and create corresponding element-access functions.

Comment: The only things that can be released with a `delete` expression are pointers that resulted from a corresponding `new` expression.  If there are any mismatches, behaviour is undefined (e.g. a `delete` expression is applied to something that wasn't the result of a corresponding `new` expression).  Your constructor is emulating creation of a 2D array, and the destructor is emulating destruction of a 3D array - hence mismatches are certain, and behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two "levels" of `new`, so three "levels" of `delete` can't be right.

Spell out your deletion loop, using indexing instead of pointer arithmetic:

```
First iteration:

delete ptr[0]+0;
delete ptr[0]+1;
...
delete ptr[0]+n-1;

delete [] ptr[0];

Second iteration:

delete ptr[1]+0;
delete ptr[1]+1;
...
delete ptr[1]+n-1;

delete [] ptr[1];
```

You're passing to `delete` a pointer to the first element of `ptr[0]`, a pointer to the second element of `ptr[0]`, a pointer to the third element of `ptr[0]`, ...
But the things you allocated were `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, ... `ptr[m-1]`, not their individual elements.

Remove the innermost deletion loop.
(And don't mess around with pointer arithmetic when you can use indexing.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you would want to allocate memory space by m length if it is set to 0 by default.
To me it looks like you set m = 0 and then try to allocate by 0 length or how do you control the length of your dimensions?

Maybe edit your constructor to:

```
MyMatrix(int m, int n)
{
    this->m = m;
    this->n = n;
    ...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the comment I may have exspressed myself too shortly I have edited the answer to match what I meant OP should do